# Обособление оборота с деепричастием, оканчивающимся на -вши

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

*И сказавши так горько расплакалась.*
Обособляется ли здесь деепричастный оборот "сказавши так"? И если обособляется — то как: вместе с союзом "и" или без?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: @oleedd Просто совет. Если уж правите вопрос, то нужно обращать внимание и на **шапку**. По тексту получается, что оборот заканчивается на "-вши". А это неверно. Думаю, надо так: _Обособление оборота с деепричастием на «-вши»._

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова А теоретически "так" может усиливать наречие (которое относится к глаголу). И смотрю, что в справочниках и словарях окончания не берутся в кавычки: дефиса уже достаточно.

Comment: @oleedd 1. Она плакала так горько, так безутешно, как плачут только в юности. Она так горько расплакалась, закрыв за собой дверь в квартиру, что Генка... 2. В печатных справочниках и словарях такие окончания обычно выделяются или курсивом, или жирным, или прописными буквами. Первые два варианта для заголовка вопроса не подходят, а третий — просто не выглядит красиво. Дело-то ведь не "во вшах".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Имею в виду, что тогда оборот будет действительно заканчиваться на *-вши*: И, сказавши, так горько расплакалась. При написании без кавычек дефис полностью исключает двусмысленность (слово "вши" и морфема *-вши*). Дефис уже играет роль выделения. Кавычки мне кажутся избыточными. И думаю, что в кавычках дефис лучше убрать, как это сделал Aer в ответе.

Comment: @oleedd _И, сказавши, так горько расплакалась._ Конечно, теоретически возможно. Но тогда это будет не деепричастный оборот, а одиночное деепричастие на -вши. Пусть будет так — без кавычек, убедили.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Подправил шапку.

Answer (score 1):

«Вши» никак не влияет на пунктуацию в предложении:

> И, сказавши так, горько расплакалась
>   или
>   И, сказавши так горько, расплакалась — в зависимости от смысла.

*И* не включается в оборот (деепричастие и зависимые от него слова можно «выбросить» из предложения, а союз *и* — нет).

Answer (score 1):

**И, сказавши так, горько расплакалась.**

Деепричастный оборот, находящийся после союза или союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (**союзы не включаются в деепричастный оборот**). Только союз А требует проверки (там возможны варианты).

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=82

2. Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой. То же **после присоединительного союза**, которым начинается предложение (союз стоит после точки): Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки, он засмеялся (М. Т.); **И, подойдя ко мне, сказал…**